# Hover effects works while running code on pc but after uploading it to server and visiing the website hover effect doesn't work

Tags: html, css, web, sass, hover

I have a website on which I used the hover effect on navigation items and the call to action button. It works perfectly when I run it on google chrome. But when I upload this on the hosting server and visit the website live, the hover effect doesn't seem to work. I don't know why does it happen?

Comment: You need to include a snippet of your code so we can see what is happening. Otherwise it is just guessing.

Comment: Which browser did you test on live?

Comment: As off @AHaworth: just guessing ... did you upload all(!) files including all css/js (means: no error on ftp upload process) ... are all css/js loaded correctly by the html (means: did you adapt the domain to the servers url if you load css/js files by url) ... is the folder structure identical (same names) if you load css/js files by relative path ... I think without code but even the link helping still remains guessing ;-)

Comment: This is my github repository link of my website:  https://github.com/shahab570/skillguardian.git